# Input loose focus instantly on Android after focused with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic App with AngularJS.

I got few inputs (signin/signup stuff) and when Enter key is pressed -go button on android and equivalent on iOS- which is `KeyCode 13`, it focuses on the next input with help a custom directive.

It works perfectly well on web browser, but on the phone, it focuses the next input, then the focus is lost instantly and the keyboard hide itself, forcing user to click again on the input.

Here is the **HTML**:

```
<ion-view title="First Screen" hide-nav-bar="true" id="firstScreen" class=" ">
<ion-content padding="false" style="background: url(img/XAYpMMdUTvWFVAnrEhUi_restaurant.jpg) no-repeat center;background-size:cover;" class=" manual-remove-top-padding" scroll="false">
    <div class="">
        <img src="img/awdYDbeeSlSHCToXN5Lw_logo.png" width="auto" height="30%" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    </div>
        <label class="item item-input " id="emailInput" name="email">
            <input class="invisible-input" type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" focus-me="currentInput == 0" ng-keyup="inputKeyEvent($event, 0)">
     </label>
    <label class="item item-input " id="passwordInput" name="password">
        <input class="invisible-input" type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe"  focus-me="currentInput == 1" ng-model="user.password" ng-keyup="inputKeyEvent($event, 1)">
    </label>
    <label  ng-show="isSignUp" class="item item-input " ng-class="{'animated fadeInLeft': isSignUp, 'animated fadeOutLeft' : !isSignUp && changed }" id="confirmPasswordInput" name="password">
        <input class="invisible-input" type="password" placeholder="Confirmation du mot de passe"  focus-me="currentInput == 2" ng-model="user.confirmation" ng-keyup="inputKeyEvent($event, 2)">
    </label>
    <div>
        {{response}}
    </div>
    <div class="actionButtonContainer">
        <button ng-click="signin()" id="loginButton" class=" button button-balanced  button-full">Se oonnecter</button>
        <button ng-click="signup()" id="signupButton" class=" button button-energized  button-full" ng-disabled="disableSignUp()">S'inscrire</button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the **directive** :

```
directive('focusMe', function() {
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.focusMe, function (value) {
            if (value === true) {
                element[0].focus();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

And here is the **controller methods** that is involved :

```
$scope.inputKeyEvent = function(event, inputId)
{
    $scope.response = event.keyCode;
    if (event.keyCode == 13)
    {
        $scope.currentInput = inputId + 1;
        if ($scope.currentInput == 2 && !$scope.isSignUp)
            $scope.signin();
        else if ($scope.currentInput == 3 && $scope.isSignUp)
            $scope.signup();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT**

The problem was my genymotion emulator, it does work perfectly on real phone (at least mine.)

Comment: Sorry for off-topic comment, but for future reference, the verb is "lose": http://grammarist.com/usage/loose-lose/

Answer (score 2):

I think you should call `blur()` method before on the unfocused element.
I have done it in ionic and cordova and it works perfectly.

Also, wrap the `focus()` on next element in a `timeout` (`$timeout` for angular version or `setTimeout` for vanillajs) so the focus will be executed in another scope and after the blur has completed.

You should have something like this:

```
$scope.inputKeyEvent = function(event, id) {
    // prevent default 
    event.preventDefault();

    // blur on the unfocused element
    event.target.blur();

    // focus on next element
    // wrapped in timeout so it will run
    // in "another thread" 
    $timeout(function() {
      // If you want to follow all angular best practices
      // Make a broadcast and read the event in the link function
      // of your directive
      var obj = document.getElementById(nextId);

      // Check if object exists
      if(obj) {
       obj.focus();
      }

    });
}
```

Comment: Well, I've figured out that the input switch focus as expected, but it seems like the problem is that the default behavior of the the enter/go button is still triggering

Comment: The problem was the emulator. Just tested it on my phone and it works.

Comment: Have you tried in older android phones? the `focus` gets a little buggy sometimes thats why we use the `blur` before

Answer (score 1):

I made a plunkr example and with my Samsung S5 it works. There isn't an issue like you describe in your question. After i press key(13) the focus jump to the next input element withour hiding keyboard or something like that.

Maybe its something with the versions. I didn't test it with a builded app. I ust open the plunkr with my smartphone. Check it out. Maybe you get some hint.

https: //plnkr.co/edit/R8uRlzQpfSg7w37nKEKH?p=preview

(Why it's not possible to post a plunkr link anymore???)